# FrameWorks to build gdata application in iphone

Tags: iphone

Hai all,which frameworks i need to build my gdata application in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

gdata is also called google data.
Details are available in the following link,

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/